# how to replace the first 2 digits of the column value where value is between 2019 to 2099

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python dataframe with about 2,500 rows and 6 columns. With one specific column I would like to replace the first 2 characters of each row in an conditional statement.

In:

```
S.No  year
1     2019
2     2020
3     2021
4     2005
5     2056
```

Out:

```
S.No  year
1     1919
2     1920
3     1921
4     2005
5     1956
```

**Code :**

```
import pandas ad pd
if data[(data['year'] >= 2019) & (data['year'] < 2099)]:
    data['year'] = data['year'].str[:2].replace('20','19')
```

Not working with this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to subtract `100` from the rows matched by the conditions:

```
m = (data['year'] >= 2019) & (data['year'] < 2099)

data['year'] = data['year'].mask(m, data['year'] - 100)
```

Or:

```
data.loc[m, 'year'] -= 100
```

---

```
print (data)
   S.No  year
0     1  1919
1     2  1920
2     3  1921
3     4  2005
4     5  1956
```